# Livereload chrome extension not responding to changes made in css or html even though gaurad-livereload 1.6 catching the changes

Tags: linux, google-chrome, livereload

I have a linux os. recently installed the livereload chrome extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei and guard-livereload server, but the livreload extension connects to the server but changes made to css or html not getting reflected in the browser.plz help.